# How I do alternate color row in listView programmatically?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android, row

I need put an alternative color some rows in listView:

[image]

**My actual code**

```
public class Agenda
{    
    List<Schedule> tabelaAgenda = new List<Schedule>();
    public ListView _listView;
    public ArrayAdapter _adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pro_AgendaDia);        
        _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView_Horas);

        ArrayList listaArray =
            populaHorarios(dataInicial.Year, dataInicial.Month, dataInicial.Day);

        _listView.Adapter = _adapter;    
        _listView.ItemClick += _listView_ItemClick;    
    }

    private ArrayList populaHorarios(int ano, int mes, int dia)
    {
         DateTime testDate = new DateTime(ano, mes, dia, horaInicial, 00, 00);    

        tabelaAgenda = Schedule.carregaDadosAgenda_Exemplos();    
        ArrayList ArrayResultante = new ArrayList();

        for (var hora = 1; hora < hoursLeft; hora++)
        {
            var pHora = testDate.Hour;
            var pMinuto = testDate.Minute;
            var result = tabelaAgenda.Where(x => x.horaini == pHora && x.minutoini == pMinuto).FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {    
                ArrayResultante.Add(testDate.ToShortTimeString() + " Scheduled");
                _adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Custom_hours_ocupied, ArrayResultante);
                // set background color GRAY
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayResultante.Add(testDate.ToShortTimeString());
                _adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Custom_hours_free, ArrayResultante);
                // set color other 
            }

            testDate = testDate.AddMinutes(30);

        } // for 

        return ArrayResultante;
    }
}
```

**XML Custom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textItensHoras1"          
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_teal_100"
    android:textColor="@color/verde_trevo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"    
  />
```

Comment: You have `override void OnCreate(...` inside `class Agenda` which does not inherit from any class. What are you overriding there? Your code will not compile.

Comment: You need to implement a custom `Adapter` to achieve different color in each `View`. What is `populaHorarios` for?

Comment: custom adapter and listitem view will do the job. in the adapter you assign the background color of the main layout item in relation to the data i.g if there is an appointment background is grey, if not its blue

Answer (score 1):

I solved!
I changed from arrayList to BaseAdapter.
Based on this print attached here.

Thanks @Orkhan Alikhanov and @user1230268 :)

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5fNC.jpg)
[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM3zP.jpg)

Comment: thanks, this got me on the right path for my project